# How to use an image taken in the 1stViewController in the 2ndViewController?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, uiimagepickercontroller

The user can choose whether he wants to use an existing image or take a new one for use as the background.

Everything works as far as the FirstViewController is concerned.  Sadly the image is no longer set as the background, when the SecondViewController is displayed.

How do I enable the use of the image as background for the SecondViewController?

I used this piece of code (in the SecondViewController):

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int bla = [prefs integerForKey:@"background_key"];
if (bla == 1) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.mac.jpg"]];
} else if (bla == 2) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black.jpg"]];
} else if (bla == 3) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinn.png"]];
} else if (bla == 4) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"]];
}
```

I tried to save the chosen image as "MyImage.png" but it looks as though it did not work. The background is black instead of the image selected.

I used this code (from the 1stViewController) to save the chosen picture as "MyImage.png":

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)anInfo {

//UIImage *selectedImage;
NSURL *mediaUrl;

mediaUrl = (NSURL *)[anInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
if (mediaUrl == nil)
{
    selectedImage = (UIImage *) [anInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if (selectedImage == nil)
    {
        selectedImage = (UIImage *) [anInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        NSLog(@"Original image picked.");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Edited image picked.");
    }
}

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
if (selectedImage != nil)
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:selectedImage];
}

// Get the image from the result
UIImage* ownImage = [anInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

// Get the data for the image as a PNG
NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ownImage);

// Give a name to the file
NSString* imageName = @"MyImage.png";

// Now, we have to find the documents directory so we can save it
// Note that you might want to save it elsewhere, like the cache directory,
// or something similar.
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// Now we get the full path to the file
NSString* fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

// and then we write it out
[imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];

return;
}
```

There must be a mistake or logical mistake.
Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageNamed is generally used to load images that are included as part of the resources of an application.

I suspect you want:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileNameAndPath];
```

Comment: Where should your code be placed?

I somehow don't get it.
Like that?
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"Path?!"]];

But what's the path then?

Thank you.. I am a little confused.

Comment: Your file will be stored in the documentsDir, based on your code. I.e. [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName]]];

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the image with similar code to how you save it instead of using `+imageNamed:`: build the full path and load it from there.

`+imageNamed:` "looks for an image with the specified name in the application’s main bundle." ([UIImage reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW10)), but that's not where you are saving it to. I don't think you can write into the application's bundle, so you won't be able to use `+imageNamed:` here.